# Show closure of image equals $\mathbb{C}$ (I.e. is dense in $\mathbb{C})$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be a nonconstant analytic function on $\mathbb{C}\backslash S$, where $S$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $\overline{f(\mathbb{C}\backslash S)}=\mathbb{C}$

In preparation for a final examination, I am reviewing various questions for complex analysis. In particular, I am not too sure how to go about solving this question. I was thinking to prove it by contradiction, and suppose that the image is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$, but am not too sure.

My apologies for the lack of work and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it is not dense. Then there exists an open disk $B(c,r)$ disjoint from $f(\mathbb C\setminus S)$. Let $g(z)=\frac 1 {f(z)-c}$ for $z \in \mathbb C\setminus S$ .  Then $g$ is analytic on $\mathbb C\setminus S$ and it is bounded there (because $|f(x)-c| \geq r$). It follows that at the points of $S$ it has a removable singularity. Hence it extends to a bounded entire function. This makes $g$ constant and hence $f$ also constant.

Comment: @S Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: Haha, I suspected this was similar to the proof showing the closure of $f(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}$. I just realized that each point in $S$ has a ball sufficiently small around it, not including that point in $S$. Thus we can extend each point to a bounded entire function. Thank you so much!